A commutative ring with unity which is also reduced having exactly two minimal prime ideals.
Let $R$ be a commutative reduced ring with unity. I want to find an example of such a ring which contains exactly two minimal prime ideals. For example if we take $\mathbb{Z_6}$ then $\langle2\rangle$ and $\langle3\rangle$ are prime ideals, but are they minimal also?

$\mathbb{Z}_6 = \mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_3$, and for product rings, prime ideals are of the from $\mathfrak{p} \times A_2 \times \dots \times A_n$, where $A_i$ is a ring and $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A_1$ is a prime ideal.


are they minimal also?

Yes, they are, because finite rings are zero dimensional.  That is to say that their prime ideals are both minimal primes and maximal primes.
So if you take any pair of fields then their product has exactly two minimal prime ideals.

Thank you very much rschwieb
